# Filter rows based on some function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following table:

```
<table>
<tr class="applyFilterOnThis">
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="timeAdded">15.03.2011 05:42</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="applyFilterOnThis">
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="timeAdded">15.03.2011 08:42</span></td>
</tr>
<tr class="applyFilterOnThis">
    <td></td>
    <td><span class="timeAdded">15.03.2011 15:42</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I want to add a class to every row that has a timeadded that is more than, say 6 hours from the client time. (If time is now 15.03.2011 17:00, only the last row gets the class added.

This is what I was looking for (don't know about the 'Filter' function):

```
 $('.applyFilterOnThis').Filter(someFunction()).addClass('markAsFiltered');
```

(I know the actual parsing of the date is a separate issue, so I'd be happy if someone just give a hint on how to use the filter function)

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Comment: Did you take a look at http://api.jquery.com/filter/ ?

Comment: Reading the documentation??? Sorry, yes, it's there. Should have tried that fist :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sturup link for you [Filter in Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)?
Code should be something like

```
$('.applyFilterOnThis').each(function(){
  if(isDateOk($(this).val())){
    $(this).addClass('markAsFiltered');
  }
});
```